# Reading e-mail attachments with Grooy/Grails + Javamail with a file size limit

Tags: groovy, jakarta-mail

I have a Groovy/Grails web app that reads e-mails from Gmail. It gets messages and attachments well, but I would like to limit the size of an attachment that I receive. Currently I have this code to read attachments:

```
byte[] file = new byte[maxSizeInBytes]

BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(part.getInputStream())
try {
    file = bis.getBytes()
} catch (Exception e) {
    ...
}
```

The problem here is that Groovy simply expands the byte array to fit whatever comes in, so if my maxSizeInBytes is set to five megabytes (5*1024*1024), and I receive an attachment that is 10 megabytes the byte array simply expands to fit the entire file. How do I limit the size here? Even better, Is there a way to get how many bytes is the attachment before actually trying to download it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `part.inputStream.available()` give you a resonable approximation?

**Edit**

Or, `part.size` probably gives you the encoded size of the attachment.  I saw [over here](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=53410) that multiplying this value by `0.65` should give you a rough approximation of the final attachment size

Comment: I tried with attachments that were 38585, 931 and 10716286 bytes each and they all returned 0 with part.inputStream.available() and part.getInputStream().available, so.. not really (unless I failed somehow).

Comment: @Joel No, sounds like it's not going to help...  I assume you tried `part.size`?

Comment: This is embarrasing, I had not tried that. `Part.size` returns an almost decent estimate, just not a very accurate one. It returned 14.6MB for the 10.2MB file, 5.2MB for the 3.8MB file and 1.2kB for the 0.9kB file. The error margin is quite large, but I think I'll use part.size at least for a sanity check of 10MB, then download the file by "manually" reading bytes with `BufferedInputStream.read(byte[], int, int)` one byte at a time and use a int byte counter to see if I get above 5MB and then abort. Modify your answer and I'll accept. Do you want a copy of my code when done?

Comment: No worries or embarassment should be taken!  Sometimes you just need another set of eyes for the answer to appear :-) ... Apparently, `size * 0.65` is a good approximation (due to the different encoding schemes used to hack binary into email)